# Порядок фильтров в сервлетах без web.xml

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, filter

Есть 3 фильтра: `Filter1, Filter2, Filter3`.
Каждый из них помечен аннотацией `@WebFilter("/main")`.
**Как задать порядок фильтров?**
Например, чтобы первым отрабатывал `Filter3`, вторым `Filter1`, третьим `Filter2`.

Comment: На en so есть такой же вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560969/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-using-annotations-in-war Там говорится, что при помощи аннотаций нельзя определить порядок. От себя добавлю, что если вы используете спринг, то это возможно.